# Using American's Admiral Lounge when I have a ticket from Gulf Air on an American-operated flight

Tags: airlines, american-airlines, lounges, gulf-air

Say I have airline status with American Airlines and would normally be able to use this airline's lounge. This time I'm flying with Gulf Air, but the flight is in fact operated by American. Would I still be able to use  the Admiral's Club while I'm at the airport?

Comment: This is a good question, as this scenario is not covered on the [lounge access](http://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/airportAmenities/lounge-access.jsp) page, and there is no information about reciprocal lounge privileges is on the [Gulf Air partnership page](http://www.aa.com/i18n/AAdvantage/earnMiles/airlines/gulf-air.jsp) (yes, I know the operating carrier is AA, but for 1W the flight quite explicitly must be both marketed and operated by a 1W carrier. These other codeshare partnerships are all unique, so one can't make assumptions either way).

Comment: I am not sure, either. I would say don't count on access but it doesn't hurt to show up and present your boarding pass.The worst they do is say no, but they might say yes.

Comment: I think the "marketed and operated" language is going to be the reason you won't be allowed access.

Comment: Is the ticket on 001 (AA) stock, or on Gulf Air stock? (Check the first 3 digits of the 12-13 digit e-ticket). I've known that make a difference

Comment: I don't think the AAdmirals staff will notice it's not marketed by AA. They certainly aren't going to be interested in the ticket number.

Answer (score 3):

You say you have "airline status" with AA. If you mean you normally can access the lounge when flying AA domestically or on an economy ticket, then you can use the AA lounge - a boarding pass should only be needed when accessing a Third Party Lounge.
The exact definitions given are "an Admirals Club annual, lifetime or 30-day member, Citi® / AAdvantage® Executive Card primary cardholder, or AirPass member with Admirals Club privileges" (http://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/airportAmenities/lounge-access.jsp)

If you are hoping to use the lounge due to the level of Gulf Air ticket you have bought, then probably not.  See the other comments/answers regarding whether it is a oneWorld ticket.

If you think you can't access the lounge, but still want to, you can always purchase a One-Day-Pass

Comment: That's not correct. For example, an AAdvantage status member accessing an AA lounge because they are travelling on an international segment (which is pretty much the only time I ever do it) always has to show their boarding pass to show they are on that international flight. It's not clear if that extends to GulfAir.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "I have airline status with American Airlines and would normally be able to use this airline's lounge," because American Airlines doesn't provide lounge access based on American Airlines status alone.  They do offer lounge access to those with Sapphire and Emerald status on any other OneWorld airline, and they provide lounge access to Executive Platinum members flying on an international flight that departs or arrived that same day and is marketed and operated by a OneWorld airline.  If you're on a flight operated by American but marketed by Gulf Air, you can try for lounge access, but it's doubtful you'd get it.

Comment: To clarify - the international thing applies to Exec Platinum *or* Platinum (and now Platinum Pro too). It does affect the "level" of the lounge you can access though. To be clear, it applies to American-operated international flights and *all* flights for other OneWorld airlines.